# How to replace NaN from Dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, nested, nan

I have the following code:

```
my_dataset={'item1':{'item11':0,'item12':'NaN','item13':2},'item2':{'item21':0,'item22':'NaN','item23':2}}
my_dataset_clean=my_dataset
for item in my_dataset:
     my_dataset_clean[item] = {k: 0 for k in my_dataset[item] if isnan(my_dataset[item][k])}
```

I am getting this error:

> my_dataset_clean[item] = {k: 0 for k in my_dataset[item] if
>   isnan(my_dataset[item][k])} TypeError: must be real number, not str

Any ideas on how to solve the issue? I want to replace NaN with 0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check `'NaN'` as a string instead of use `isnan` (presumably `np.isnan`) which expects a numeric value. But there are a few other points worth noting:

1. You don't define what happens when your value is *not* `'NaN'`. Without this you will lose the other items. See below for how you can define a ternary statement.
2. `my_dataset_clean = my_dataset` does not create a copy of your dictionary. You need to be explicit, e.g. `my_dataset_clean = my_dataset.copy()`, to do this. Otherwise you just have 2 variables pointing to the same dictionary.
3. You can use a dictionary comprehension to avoid having to make a copy of your dictionary.

Here's an example with a dictionary comprehension and ternary statement:

```
my_dataset_clean = {k: {k2: 0 if v2 == 'NaN' else v2 for k2, v2 in v.items()} \
                    for k, v in my_dataset.items()}
```

Here `k, v` refer to keys / values in the outer dictionary, and `k2, v2` refer to keys / values in inner dictionaries.

Comment: Many thanks for the 3 points. Your example is exactly what I wanted to achieved

Answer (score 1):

`'NaN'` in your dictionaries is a string. Instead of `isnan` you can just use string comparison: `my_dataset[item][k] == 'NaN'`.